# A utility to backup single tables on MSSQL?

Tags: windows, sql-server, database-backup

Are there any Windows utilities that allow you back up single MSSQL tables? Having a lot or trouble finding any. I hear [sqlbackupandftp](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/) is good, but as far as I can see, it doesn't back up single tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What database backup utility should I use?](http://serverfault.com/questions/303396/what-database-backup-utility-should-i-use)

Comment: Agree this is a duplicate.  Use the built-in MSSQL backup functionality and save the off to separate storage once a day.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to backup a single table.  You can BCP tables out using the OUT syntax.

```
bcp YourDatabase.Owner.Table OUT d:\Yourfile.ext
```

This will dump the contents of a single table to an output file.

If you were to dump two tables from the database they would not be transactionly consistent with each other.  Because of this, this would not be a good way to backup your database.